# Buffer overrun while writing to 'array': the writable size is '1*4' bytes, but '8' bytes might be written

Tags: c++

I am filling an empty array with randomly generated numbers between 0 and 100000 but the line "array[i] = rand() % 100000;" has a green underline and says "Buffer overrun while writing to 'array': the writable size is '1*4' bytes, but '8' bytes might be written". Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <time.h>
#pragma

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int N;
    cout << "Enter a value for N: ";
    cin >> N;
    int* array = new int(N);
    srand(time(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        array[i] = rand() % 100000;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        cout << array[i] << ", ";
    }

    delete array;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For starters, try int* array = new int[N];

Answer (score 4):

`new int(N);` creates a *single* `int` with the initial value `N`.

For an array, write `new int[N];`

To free this memory you need to write `delete[] array;`: the behaviour of `delete array;` will be undefined.

Note that a drop-in replacement that takes care of all the memory management for you would be

```
std::vector<int> array(N);
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed the problem

Comment: @Niall: Naturally ;-) Note that professional programmers will use `std::vector<int>` - do try that one out too.